# why correlation computed by nump.cov() and np.std() is different from the result computed by np.corrcoef()

Tags: python, numpy

I wish someone could help me answer why Correlation result computed by `numpy.cov()` and `np.std()` is different from the result computed directly by `np.corrcoef()`.

the following code show the difference

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = np.random.rand(50)
Y = np.random.rand(50)

plt.scatter(X,Y)
plt.xlabel('X Value')
plt.ylabel('Y Value')

# taking the relevant value from the matrix returned by np.cov
print 'Correlation: ' + str(np.cov(X,Y)[0,1]/(np.std(X)*np.std(Y)))
# Let's also use the builtin correlation function
print 'Built-in Correlation: ' + str(np.corrcoef(X, Y)[0, 1])
```

One Example output:

> Correlation: -0.0972430699897
>
> Built-in Correlation: -0.0952982085899

Comment: Check the documentation on np.corrcoef (which calls np.cov) and np.std.  I believe that np.std is using an "n-1" standard deviation calculation while np.cov is using "n" instead.   If this is correct, then the difference will be quite small for very large vectors.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the suggest from **Brian Borchers**

After checking the document, the difference is due to the parameter `ddof`(delta degrees of freedom) of `np.std()`  defaults to `0`, while `1` is used in `np.corrcoef()`

Modified as the following, the code can generate the same results:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = np.random.rand(50)
Y = np.random.rand(50)

plt.scatter(X,Y)
plt.xlabel('X Value')
plt.ylabel('Y Value')

# taking the relevant value from the matrix returned by np.cov
print 'Correlation: ' + str(np.cov(X,Y)[0,1]/(np.std(X,ddof=1)*np.std(Y,ddof=1)))
# Let's also use the builtin correlation function
print 'Built-in Correlation: ' + str(np.corrcoef(X, Y)[0, 1])
```

Example output:

> Correlation: -0.174042621953
>
> Built-in Correlation: -0.174042621953